# How to run for each loop on value extracted from regular expression extractor

Tags: xpath, jmeter, extractor

Problem Statement: in my API response, I am getting same set of xml tag repeated multiple times but with different values of the underlying tags which are also repeating across xml response. Also those two underlying values have mapping to each other. I need to extract all the mappings from response and write them to SQL. I am having trouble with extracting the mapping values from the API response.

I am trying to use regular expression extractor to fetch that repetitive main tag which hold those two values. Then I am trying to use for each loop on the output variable of regular expression extractor. And will then write respective values to target table for each of the iteration.

Following tag is repeating multiple times for each cycle. I need to fetch the two values present under `<Value>` tag for each of the `<Object>` tag. For example '{abc-def}' and 'D12345' in this case for this particular instance....and so on.

```
<Object classId="QueryResultRow"><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonId" propertyId="Id"><Value>{abc-def}</Value></Property><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonString" propertyId="DCN"><Value>D12345</Value></Property></Object>
```

I am unable to get the required two values from each of the tag while retaining the mapping. Also, I am not sure how to use only one of the generated variable from the output of regular expression as it's creating 4 types of variables for each target xml tag.

```
objVal=<Object classId="QueryResultRow"><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonId" propertyId="Id"><Value>{abc-def}</Value></Property><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonString" propertyId="DCN"><Value>D112345</Value></Property></Object>
objVal_g=1
objVal_g0=<Object classId="QueryResultRow"><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonId" propertyId="Id"><Value>{abc-def}</Value></Property><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonString" propertyId="DCN"><Value>D12345</Value></Property></Object>
objVal_g1=<Property i:type="fn40:SingletonId" propertyId="Id"><Value>{abc-def}</Value></Property><Property i:type="fn40:SingletonString" propertyId="DCN"><Value>D12345</Value></Property>
```

I would need to use only objVal from here and I am trying to use

1. [Regular expression extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JG91G.png)
2. [Flow of my Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY3w3.png)
3. [For Each loop to extract object tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVqFL.png)
4. [second for loop to extract two values out of extracted object tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8HH3.png)
5. [use of variable created in 4th step in my jdbc sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af5Hq.png)

Answer (score 0):

After you have xml in `objVal` variable,

Use [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) using `JMeter variable Name to use` your `objVal` variable

Use `XPath query` as `/Object/Property/Value`

And if Match No. is `-1` you will get all values

```
objVal_value={abc-def}
aa_value_1={abc-def}
aa_value_2=D112345
```

> allows the user to extract value(s) from structured response - XML or (X)HTML - using XPath query language

Comment: So objVal will have all the variables like objVal,objVal_g,objVal_g0,objVal_g1. and that will be same structure for all the different objects. I have to iterate over all the objects which mean I would be looping over all the objects 4 times as there are 4 variables getting generated for each object. I want to loop over only one - "objVal" else I would end up having repetition in my result set. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @vsingh don't you just need `{abc-def}` and `D112345`?

Comment: that's right. I just need to extract {abc-def} and D12345
But there are going to be multiple instances of . objectIDs in the response, so there will be multiple mappings of these two values and . I need to extract all of them. That's why I am using Match no as '-1' so that all the matches get extracted in regular expression extractor and get stored in objval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regular expression to fetch the required values.

```
propertyId="Id"><Value>(.*?)</Value>(.*)propertyId="DCN"><Value>(.*?)</Value>
```

[image]

The values will be present in the below variables.

objval_1_g0

objval_1_g2

objval_2_g0

objval_2_g2

objval_3_g0

objval_3_g2

objval_4_g0

objval_4_g2

You can use a debug sampler to check the variables value.